# Matplotlib's Title and Suptitle Don't Align Properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn, data-visualization

I have made a `seaborn` heatmap. I am trying to have a title and a subtitle using `matplotlib`; however, the titles aren't aligning the same.

[image]

What can I do to fix this messed up alignment?

Here is the code I used to make the heatmap.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.heatmap(my_heatmap, cmap='RdYlGn', vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.title('10 mm Precipitation Probabilities', fontsize = 14)
plt.suptitle('Topeka, Kansas', fontsize = 16)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `suptitle` is associated with the Figure object. `subtitle` is associated with the Axes object

Comment: @PaulH matplotlib.pyplot has no attribute 'subtitle'

Comment: errr...`title`. it's early on the US west coast